# Immutable object initialisation in JAVA

Tags: java, class, object, immutability

How can I create an object of an 'immutable' class 'Aim' when using the following code:

Aim a = new Aim(2,3).coordinateChange(2,1).scale(0.5);

so 'a' gets initialised with (2,2) point coordinate
-- coordinateChange should add values to x,y coordinates
-- scale should scale them i.e. 50% in the above example

I know how to do it without an immutable class but don't know how the class should look if the above code to be used to initialise a final object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to make each of the `coordinateChange` and `scale` methods return a new `Aim` object, since you can't change the original one that you created.  That means that your `Aim` class would have to contain something like

```
public Aim coordinateChange(double changeInX, double changeInY) {
    return new Aim(x + changeInX, y + changeInY);
}

public Aim scale(double scaleFactor) {
   return new Aim(x * scaleFactor, y * scaleFactor);
}
```

You can see that each of these methods contains `new Aim( ...`, so is actually making a brand new object.

The `x` and `y` mentioned in each method are the fields of your `Aim` class, so you may want to rename these if you're using different names for these.